# How can I set up cloud code (for an existing project) on a new machine?

Tags: parse-platform

I have an existing parse.com project with some hosted code and some cloud code. I have a new machine that I would like to move the development to and have found no way in the documentation on how to do this.

I wish to hook up to an existing project with my parse command-line tool (Windows) and get the current files in that project to my machine, how do I do this?

Looking at the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-setting-up-cloud-code), there seems only to be a way to set up a new project, to create new files. Running the commands;

```
> parse new Project1
Email: xxx@gmail.com
Password:
Select application:
1:Project1
Select an App: 1
```

will only create a new folder and not containing the files that are already in that project.

Is there any way to get round this or do I manually have to move the files and redeploy from the new machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible out of the box. You would need to copy the files from your old machine to your new machine and then you should be able to deploy from there.

A possible workflow to make this easier in the future would be to host the Cloud Code you write on a server (preferably using some sort of source control) and let the server deploy any changes that get pushed to the repo so you have one centralized place that holds the latest code and it is easy to work on it as a team.

Comment: Seems that this isn't really the "optimal" solution, but after reading more and more about it, it seems that this is the only way.